# Typescript difference between using type check and generic

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm in the middle of a typescript course. We're learning generics and the following example is shown

```
const hobbies: Array<string> = ['coding', 'eating']
```

Now before I learned to check an array of type using the following syntax

```
const hobbies: string[] = ['coding', 'eating']
```

Can anyone explain me what the difference is?

Answer (score 2):

Those two mean the same thing. So i can see that as a useful example for introducing the concept of generics, since it takes a concept you're already familiar with (arrays) and shows another way it can be done. But generics can also be used in a broader range of contexts than just arrays.

Comment: What's the preferred method you think?

Comment: The way I handle it: simple types with `string[]`, more complicated types (e.g. union types, in-line object types) w/ `Array<string l number>` since it’s more readable in my opinion.